# How do I see which code is executed when clicking the Start button on the AX 2012 R2 ProdTable form?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

ProdTable form, Production Order tab, Process group, Start.

Looking through the form designer, I can find the MenuItem in the DesignList, but the methods are empty. Where can I see which code is being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click the button in the `Design List`, and click Properties
- Note the properties `MenuItemType` (`Action`) & `MenuItemName`
  (`ProdStartUpAction`)
- Back in the AOT, browse to `Menu Items` and expand `Action`
- Find `ProdStartUpAction` in the list
- Right click `ProdStartUpAction` and click Properties
- Note the properties `ObjectType` (`Class`) and `Object` (`ProdMultiSatrtUp`)
- Back in the `AOT`, browse to `Classes`
- **Expand the class `ProdMultiStartUp` - the method the menu item runs is
  called Main**